# SQL query to show good records as well as null records

Tags: sql-server, null, left-join, inner-join

My query works perfectly well to find records with real values, however, I also need my query to show records with null values. So far my attempts at recreating this query to also show null values has resulted in losing at least 1 of my columns of results so now I'm looking for help.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT sq.*, sq.TransactionCountTotal - sq.CompleteTotal as InProcTotal from 
(
select 
c.CustName,
t.[City],
sum (t.TransactionCount) as TransactionCountTotal
sum (
    case 
        when (
            [format] in (23,25,38) 
            or [format] between 400 and 499 
            or format between 800 and 899
            )
    then t.TransactionCount
    else 0
    end
) as CompleteTotal
FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t
INNER JOIN [log].[dbo].[Customer] c
    on t.CustNo = c.CustNo
    and t.City = c.City
    and t.subno = c.subno
where t.transactiondate between '7/1/16' and '7/11/16'
group by c.CustName,t.City
) sq
```

This is currently what my query results show:

```
CustName    City    InProcTotal TransactionCountTotal   Complete Total
Cust 1     City(a)      23               7                    30
Cust 2     City(b)      74               2                    76
Cust 3     City(c)      54               4                    58
```

This is what I want my query results to show:

```
CustName    City    InProcTotal TransactionCountTotal   Complete Total
Cust 1     City(a)      23               7                    30
Cust 2     City(b)      74               2                    76
Cust 3     City(c)      54               4                    58
Cust 4     City(d)      0                0                    0
Cust 5     City(e)      0                0                    0
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `RIGHT JOIN` in the place of `INNER JOIN`. You should then retain the rows from `Customer` that don't have matching rows in `TransactionSummary`.

You may also want to refactor the query like this so you use `LEFT JOIN`. The next person to work on the query will thank you; `LEFT JOIN` operations are more common.

```
FROM [log].[dbo].[Customer] c
LEFT JOIN [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t
on t.CustNo = c.CustNo
and t.City = c.City
```

Comment: When I use `RIGHT JOIN` I'm getting a few extra results but they show the Custname = NULL when I should be getting `sum (t.TransactionCount) as TransactionCountTotal` equal to NULL

Comment: I'm sorry, I attempted Left Join and shared the results in the answer below this one. I felt adding the information about Right Join might have been helpful as well so I posted those results under this answer..

Answer (score 0):

jwabsolution, your issue stems from grabbing all transactions instead of all customers.   My mind works in this way: you want to select all of the customers & find all transaction states.  Therefore, you should be selecting from the customer table.  Also, you shouldn't use the INNER JOIN or you will ignore any customers that don't have transactions.  Instead, use left join the transactions table.  In this manner, you will retrieve all customers (even those with no transactions).  Here is a good visual for SQL joins: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT sq.*, sq.TransactionCountTotal - sq.CompleteTotal as InProcTotal from 
(
select 
c.CustName,
t.[City],
sum (t.TransactionCount) as TransactionCountTotal
sum (
    case 
        when (
            [format] in (23,25,38) 
            or [format] between 400 and 499 
            or format between 800 and 899
            )
    then t.TransactionCount
    else 0
    end
) as CompleteTotal
FROM [log].[dbo].[Customer] c
LEFT JOIN [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t
    on c.CustNo = t.CustNo
    and c.City = t.City
    and c.subno = t.subno
where t.transactiondate between '7/1/16' and '7/11/16'
group by c.CustName,t.City
) sq
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an identical set of results but I will keep at it, maybe I am overlooking something - it was a long weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Needed to use coalesce to get the values to show up properly.

Also added a "where" option if I want to query individual customers

```
SELECT sq.* ,sq.TransactionCountTotal - sq.CompleteTotal as [InProcTotal]
    from
(
select
        c.custname
        ,c.port
        ,sum(coalesce(t.transactioncount,0)) as TransactionCountTotal
        ,sum(
            case when (
                    [format]in(23,25,38)
                    or[format]between 400 and 499
                    or[format]between 800 and 899)
                then t.TransactionCount
                else 0 
                end) as CompleteTotal
    from log.dbo.customer c
    left join log.dbo.TransactionSummary t
    on c.custNo=t.custno
    and c.subno=t.subno
    and c.city=t.city
    and t.transactiondate between '7/1/16' and '7/12/16'
    /*where c.custname=''*/
    group by c.custname,c.city
) sq
```